# C++ Char errors

Tags: c++, char

So I'm trying to take the second to first character from `Expresie` which is a char array and copy it into a char variable, and then use the `strcat` function to place that variable at the end of another char array `Stiva`. this is the code:

```
int SHIFT(char Expresie[], char Stiva[], int x)
{
        char a=Expresie[0];
        strcat(Stiva,a);
```

And this is how they are defined in main:

```
    int main()
{
    char Expresie[100];
    char Stiva[100];
```

The problem is that when i run it it says : invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] not just fragments

Comment: why dont you use `std::string`?

Comment: @Nina strcat requires a const char* as source, a char is not null terminated, that would likely end up with a segfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcat` appends strings, not characters - it wants a pointer to the first character of a "C string", not a single `char`.

The simplest way to do this is to add the character directly at the end yourself (assuming that there is room, of course):

```
int SHIFT(char Expresie[], char Stiva[], int x)
{
    char a=Expresie[0];
    size_t length = strlen(Stiva);
    Stiva[length] = a;
    Stiva[length+1] = 0;
    // ...
```